# Ember this.get('controller') returns a parent controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a `graphHolderController` that renders this template:

```
{{#each controller.graphs}}
  {{view sidePanelView}}
  {{view graph}}
{{/each}}
```

In the `SidePanelView`, I want to call a method on `SidePanelController`, but I find that in `SidePanelView`, `this.get('controller')` returns an instance of the `graphHolderController`. How can I call a method on the `SidePanelController` from the `SidePanelView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a view to be managed by its own separate controller, I'd recommend using the render helper: `{{render sidePanel}}`. This will render the `side_panel` template, backed by the `sidePanelView` and a singleton `sidePanelController`.

If the `sidePanelController` needs to manage state for a particular model, pass that model in as a context: `{{render sidePanel this}}` (where `this` represents a model). This will generate a new non-singleton `sidePanelController` to manage just this model. Since you're rendering within an `{{each}}` block, I'd guess you want to take this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `{{view}}` helper does render the view you passed as first parameter, but binds the same controller as in the parent view.

Move your method to `graphHolderController` and send the model as parameter for that action if you need to know which graph the action comes from.

Comment: Maybe I should use `{{control sidePanelView}}` instead?

Comment: Yes that is also the possibility, but I did not wanted to advice usage of unfinished feature that `{{control}}` is right now.